# How do I get information about the view state on a force.com site page?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I know that the [development mode footer](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_tools_edit_toolbar.htm) has an option to show the view state which I've used before when developing internal Salesforce pages; however, I don't see how that can be used on a force.com site page.

How do I get information about the view state when working with a Force.com site page?  Ideally, the solution would work for force.com site authenticated (via customer portal auth) pages as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just access it using /apex/[Custom Page]? They are all Visualforce pages.

Comment: Yes.  I don't see which user I would be able to turn the development mode footer on for.

Comment: That did work for the public page.  There are some other pages that require authentication and only display correctly based on certain attributes that are specific to the application.  So I think that solution works for the public pages, but not my authenticated pages.  I also do some url rewriting and the pages aren't actually accessible, but rather a template that includes them dynamically is the only page available.  I had to add them to the profile/site list of pages. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  It seems obvious now. ;)  I was thinking just about accessing the page through the site URL of mysite.csX.force.com/mySite/mySitePage and not through the SFinstance/apex/myPageName URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For pages that don't require customer portal authentication, you can access them through https://[instance].salesforce.com/apex/[page name]. This gives you the entire development mode footer.

I don't have a solution for pages that may require authentication with a specific user.

Comment: @peterKnolle Just ran across this; I ended up testing for `UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Standard'` as a backdoor way to avoid authentication where otherwise the user would be Guest. Thus, view state is avail per normal `\apex\pagename`.  That said, we aren't using customer portal and instead have a home grown SSO-controlled authentication regime for intranet users access to Sites pages

Answer (score 3):

Go to Setup -> User Profile -> Select 'Show View State in Development Mode'. At the bottom of your Visualforce page you will see 3 tabs -> Visualforce page, Apex Class and View State. Click on View State to get more information on the state of your Visualforce page.