# How to inspect View State for Community User VF page/controller

Tags: apex, governorlimits, viewstate

I would know if there is a method to know size of ViewState in a Controller Apex.

I read Limit Apex Class but I don't find a method about this scope.

I want debug a Community User and I don't find a way to active Developer Mode on it.
Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot know the size of the view state in Apex.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you just inspect the view state as a standard user. It shouldn't be radically different?

Comment: Because I receive error page only for a User.

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8992/debug-viewstate-problems-in-force-com-sites-vf-pages?rq=1 for workarounds

Comment: I would recommend a more detailed question, including some code, so that we can possibly identify why a specific user might be getting a larger view state than others.